# Oracle to csv export - HTML characters entities

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, special-characters, export-to-csv

I am working on a export procedure in Oracle. In table, special characters are stored like &#201, &#233, &#235 etc. When I export those characters, how to convert to its original value?

I am using UTL_FILE functions to export to csv. Procedure is,

```
PROCEDURE PROC_FILE_WRITE_TEST(p_dir IN VARCHAR2,p_filename IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_fh utl_file.file_type;
  c NUMBER; 
  d NUMBER; 
  v_ret NUMBER;
  col_cnt INTEGER;
  rec_tab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
BEGIN
  v_fh := utl_file.fopen(p_dir, p_filename, 'W' ,32767 );
  c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'query here', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);
  d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
LOOP
  v_ret := DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(c);
  EXIT WHEN v_ret = 0;
  UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_fh, 1);
  FOR j in 1..col_cnt
  LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT(v_fh,v_v_val||'|');
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_fh);
END PROC_FILE_WRITE_TEST;
```

Below is as example.

Table data:

```
Caf&#233; and bars
```

CSV :

> Café and bars

Comment: Not sure how this has anything to do with oracle. Since you do not show any of your code, hard to determine what is going on.   Looks like those are encodings for UTF-8 characters that are not in ASCII range. See here - https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=dec .  SO how that is decoded is completely dependant on the host environment, language locale, etc.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code sample.

Comment: This code does not work. Variable `v_v_val` is not declared or used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to help you since you hardly provide any information. However, the [UNESCAPE_REFERENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71170) may help you.

```
select UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE ( 'Caf&#233; and bars') as txt 
from dual;

TXT
=====================
Café and bars
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Replace `UTL_FILE.PUT(v_fh,v_v_val||'|')` by `UTL_FILE.PUT(v_fh,UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(v_v_val)||'|')`

Comment: Yes. I have modified my procedure and its working fine. Thanks for your help.